# Automate/handle 5th dropdown url https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ named as Github users(Aysnc with fetch.js)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have problem to automate this drop down using selenium web driver using Java

[This](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) is the link - Go to 5th drop down named as Github users (fetch. js)

I am not able to enter the data into search field. 
I am using send keys after perform click but it throws an exception like this " element is not interact able"
Steps I follow

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xapth")).click
```

drop down opens with no options because it is searchable and options are coming dynamically after entering key word into the search field.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xapth")).sendkeys("Test");
```

Sendkeys are not working in this case because of drop down closed when perform send keys action.

```
<div class="Select-placeholder">Select...</div>
```

Comment: Your xpath is not correct. Can you please share the xpath you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    public void typeAndSelect() {
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='section'][5]//div[@class='Select-control']"));
        searchBox.click();

        WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='section'][5]//input[@role='combobox']"));
        inputField.clear();

        String searchWord = "test";

        inputField.sendKeys(searchWord);

        WebElement selectDropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-menu-outer']//div[@role='option'][text()='" + searchWord +"']"));

        // wait for search results.
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(selectDropdown)).click();
    }
```

Correct the following xpath part

> "//div[@class='section'][5]"

to your implementation of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which is working. 
Please do optimize the code by removing thread.Sleep and putting some meaningful waits as per your requirement.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/");
IWebElement element1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='react-select-6--value']"));
IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='react-select-6--value']/div[2]/input[1]")) ;
element1.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
element2.SendKeys("Test");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
element2.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

Please note that element2 gets activated once you click on element1.